# Sharing RAM with GPU

Tags: python, performance, memory, cuda, theano

I have a model for deep learning which is at the edge of allocation memory error(weight matrices). I trimmed the model's complexity to the level where it works fine for my predictions(but it could be better) and it works fine with my RAM memory, however when I switch theano to use gpu for much faster training (GPU with 2GB gddr5 vram), it throws allocation error.

I searched a lot for how to share RAM with GPU and many people state that it is **not possible**(without references or explanation) and that even if you could, it would be slow. And there are always one or two people on the forums who state it could be done (I checked the whole page 1 on google search), but again a very unreliable information without anything to support it.

I understand their slowness argument, but is it slower to use GPU + RAM than using CPU + RAM for matrix heavy computations in deep learning? Nobody ever mentions that. Because all arguments I've read (like buy new card, set lower settings) were about gaming and that makes sense to me as you head to better just-in-time performance and not the overall speed.

My blind guess is that the bus that connects GPU to RAM is just the narrowest pipe in the system(slower than RAM), so it makes better sense to use CPU + RAM(which has really fast bus) over faster GPU (+  RAM). Otherwise, it wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because memory sharing is not a programming question. It is about hardware, architecture and maybe the operating system and its drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Since you tagged your question with CUDA I can give you the following answer.

With [Managed memory](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/) you can from a kernel reference memory that may or may not be on the CPU memory. In this way, the GPU memory kind of works like cache, and you are not limited by the actual GPU memory size.

Since this is a software technique I would say this is on-topic for SO.

Comment: assuming OP wants to rewrite theano or the like to used managed memory, under that circumstance  this might be on-topic.  However that wouldn't be my guess from such a question.  and what you're referring to could only be sensible for Pascal GPUs.  For other GPU families currently, managed memory does not allow you to allocate a memory size accessible to the GPU that is larger than the physical ram on the GPU.